# Where the data from variable $address in the file form-edit-address.php come from?

Tags: forms, variables, woocommerce

Hello I'm trying to edit the `my-account.php` and I'm calling the `form-edit-address.php` with the `wc_get_template()` like this:

`<?php  wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-edit-address.php' ); ?>`

But I'm getting this error:

`Notice: Undefined variable: address in .../woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-address.php on line 42`

I tried to fix that adding this line:

`$address = WC()->countries->get_address_fields();`

to the `form-edit-address.php` file.

But that doesn't work because this `$address` variable don't have the `'value'` just the name of the fields.

When I access the `form-edit-address.php` directly using this URL: http://192.168.1.15/e-commerce/my-account/edit-address/billing/ the variable `$address` comes with all the information needed.

How can get I all the data needed to generate the populated form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is 2 years old, but I was looking for the exact same thing today. Because this showed up first in google, when I googled it. And the answer has changed now.

The `$address` var is set in `class-wc-shortcode-my-account.php` and preparing the array to be in the correct format is all done there.

In the function `edit_address` line 158.

`$load_address` is just a variable set to either 'billing' or 'shipping' depending on which address you want to load.

So here's how I managed to output a edit billing address form:

```
$load_address = sanitize_key( 'billing' );

$address = WC()->countries->get_address_fields( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $load_address . '_country', true ), $load_address . '_' );

    // Prepare values
    foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) {

      $value = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), $key, true );

      if ( ! $value ) {
        switch ( $key ) {
          case 'billing_email' :
          case 'shipping_email' :
            $value = $current_user->user_email;
            break;
          case 'billing_country' :
          case 'shipping_country' :
            $value = WC()->countries->get_base_country();
            break;
          case 'billing_state' :
          case 'shipping_state' :
            $value = WC()->countries->get_base_state();
            break;
        }
      }

      $address[ $key ]['value'] = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_field_value', $value, $key, $load_address );
    }

    //Output code from form-edit-address.php
    foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) {
        if ( isset( $field['country_field'], $address[ $field['country_field'] ] ) ) {
            $field['country'] = wc_get_post_data_by_key( $field['country_field'], $address[ $field['country_field'] ]['value'] );
        }
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, wc_get_post_data_by_key( $key, $field['value'] ) );
    }
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking for the same information.

And if you want your form on a non WC page, you'll need to enqueue the country and address scripts.

```
// Enqueue scripts
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-country-select' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-address-i18n' );
```

For me I'm just trying to streamline my checkout process, so I didn't need them as I'm creating a custom cart/checkout system.

Answer (score 1):

`form-edit-address.php` gets called on accessing endpoint url "edit-address".
i.e "www.example.com/my-account/edit-address/". Which endpoint url file inherits data passed from parent page url i.e. "my-account".
Thus it won't work if you are calling the endpoint url file.

By the way, if you check into `my-address.php`, `$address` variable is defined at line number 49.

```
$address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', array(
                    'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),
                    'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
                    'company'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_company', true ),
                    'address_1'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_1', true ),
                    'address_2'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_2', true ),
                    'city'        => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_city', true ),
                    'state'       => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_state', true ),
                    'postcode'    => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_postcode', true ),
                    'country'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_country', true )
                ), $customer_id, $name );
```

This array is used in "form-edit-address.php".

If you calling the "form-edit-address.php" as the template file, try adding above code just before the foreach loop in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this variables ```$address``` are different. The ```$address``` from the file ```my-address.php``` isn't used to generate the form, just to print the information, I used the ```print_r( $address )``` to check the data structure and isn't the same.

Comment: Sure it is not used to generate the form and only to print the information. But the same information is passed on to edit form to load. The `$name` variable in above code (on `my-address.php`) decides whether it is 'billing' or 'shipping'. In the above code try changing the variable `$name` with `$load_address`. I think that should solve the problem.

Comment: changing the  ```$name``` to ```$load_address``` will just get different data, shipping or billing, but the data structure will be the same and will not work with the original ```form-edit-address.php``` file. Is possible to reproduce the same ```$address``` variable avaliable when I access the end point?